# How to automatically choose package manager based on project? e.g. npm, pnpm or yarn?

Tags: bash, npm, yarnpkg, pnpm

I have multiple projects on my laptop. Each project uses a specific package manager:

- project 1: npm
- project 2: pnpm
- project 3: yarn

When doing operations on a project I have to remember what package manager to use. In case of 30 projects it becomes troublesome.

Is there a way to do it automatically from Bash console? Ideally I'd imagine a tool that works like this:

- I place a .package-manager file in the folder
- Inside i type the name of the package manager for example "yarn"

Once done, instead of using a specific package manager I use the generic command like:

```
package run dev
```

When called, the command checks the package manager in the .package-manager file, and runs appropriate command for a given project:

- project 1: npm run dev
- project 2: pnpm run dev
- project 3: yarn run dev

etc.

Do you know any solution or tool that would make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function :

```
package(){ 
    declare pm=.package-manager 
    if test -f $pm; then 
        pm="$(cat $pm)"
    else 
        pm=yarn # default pm 
    fi 
    "$pm" "$@" 
}
```

then launch with `package run dev`